# How can you design a user flow when you don't know the functionality?

Tags: ux-designer

I am currently designing a user flow diagram on lucid chart. I am working on the "search" section. We know we want a normal search e.g. user types in their keyword or keyphrase, but we also know we want an advanced search too where user may filter by how they want to "feel" e.g. happy, excited etc.

This is not certain, we may have multiple, or singular ideas for this - how do I design without knowing this info?

Comment: Surely, regardless of the UI solution, the 'process' is still going to be "run search -> apply filter -> see results" - If you're trying to write mouse clicks and key presses into the flow then you're simply going to need a separate flow for every different filter solution.

Comment: As Andrew said, the input->process->output will be the same regardless of how it functions. That's generally all you need to map out a flow. Isn't it? You can still make the flow and then move onto iterations of how it might function, then return to the flow and make any adjustments.

Answer (score 2):

I think that’s the whole point of predesign modeling - describing how it would work in broad strokes at a high level, but free of design detail. It’s appropriate in your case for the Advanced branch to just have a “input” flow chart element with the label TBD.

Answer (score 0):

Great answers here, and I'll offer that **competitive research** is especially useful to identify design patterns. Especially for certain niches like auto (how most companies handle search & filtering) or even online dating.

Comment: You could improve your answer if you offered a definition, explanation and sources for competitive research. Welcome to UX stack